# getting multi-tiered JS object into Python via Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am building a Django app.

I need to build a JS object that is pretty simple, looks like this:

```
      data = {0: {t1: v("#t1"), p1: v("#p1")}, 
              1: {t2: v("#t2"), p2: v("#p2")},
              2: {t3: v("#t3"), p3: v("#p3")}, 
              3: {t4: v("#t4"), p4: v("#p4")}, 
              4: {t5: v("#t5"), p5: v("#p5")}, 
              5: {t6: v("#t6"), p6: v("#p6")}, 
              6: {t7: v("#t6"), p7: v("#p6")}, 
              7: {t8: v("#t8"), p8: v("#p8")},
          numTickers: 8
         };
```

FYI, v() is just a function that would be a macro in other languages...all it does is reduce typing to get values from tags.  It works, so that is not the issue: on the console, I have the right JS object with proper key/value pairs nested right.

Before AJAX I do a:

```
    var xmitData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Since that gets me closest.
My AJAX call looks (right now) like this:

```
  $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',   
      headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
      data:  xmitData,
      url: 'ajax/data',
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(data) {
```

However, what I get in Python after Django handles this is a querydict that looks munged:

```
<QueryDict: {'{"0":{"t1":"1","p1":"100"},"1":{"t2":"","p2":""},"2":{"t3":"","p3":""},"3":{"t4":"","p4":""},"4":{"t5":"","p5":""},"5":{"t6":"","p6":""},"6":{"t7":"","p7":""},"7":{"t8":"","p8":""},"numTickers":8}': ['']}>
```

To me, this says that JS/JQuery used ALL of the multi-level key/value pairs as a big key, with the value [''] (note the single quotes).

I have tried stringify, $.params, and every way to unpack on the Python end.  Oddly, this representation is precisely right *but only within the single quotes of the querydict.*  A hack way to fix this would be to extract what is between the single quotes and go from there, but that can't be right.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you don't stringify your data and just send that directly?

Comment: no better.  It actually get more confused.

Comment: Can you post the view code that handles the request?

Comment: What is shown in the GET preview section in the network area of chrome for that end point? Wanna see whats getting posted to your backend. Also view could would be helpful. Also if you plan on having many rest end points, i'd recommend checking out django rest framework. It specializes in these kinds of communications. I'd recommend just using it anyways honestly, it makes life easier.

Comment: where are docs on Django rest?

Comment: to georgeofallages:

Comment: to George...it looks like this